# The embeded Hyperlinks & Enlarge Image are not opening in Chrome Browser through MS-Teams Bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot, adaptive-cards, azure-qna-maker

The requirement is printing the FAQ ( QnA Maker result consider as an attachment in Adaptive Card Body ) contents in MS Team Bot ( HR Bot ). The core technology that we are using is C# with ASP.NET Core, Bot Framework SDK.

**FAQ Bot Example:**

- User is asking payroll related details in MS Team Bot.
- The response contains payroll document details ( Embedded as URL with bold or italic ).
- All responses return as an attachment ( Adding this response in attachment in adaptivae card body and after that posting using send activity ).
- AdaptiveCard version is 1.2

It's a FAQ bot and there are no code changes happening yet for the last two weeks. All these issues were encountered after the chrome latest updates ( [Chrome updates](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/)).

We have tried the following scenario for the embedded hyperlink issue.

1. The Following answer hyperlink is opening on the MS-Teams app

[image]

Markdown Syntax in the QnA Maker

[image]

2. The Following answer is not opening on the MS-Teams app( embedded hyperlink is changed to Bold/Italic)

[image]

Answer Markdown Syntax in the QnA Maker

[image]

**Note:**

- Opening MS teams bot in a Firefox Browser, then all scenarios are
  working.
- Opening MS teams Bot in a Chrome Browser, then the second point is not working as I mentioned above
- The detailed discussion on the same issue [posted on github](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/6431) - expecting a quick fix because of customer need.

**Enlarge Image Issue:**

We are facing a similar issue mentioned in [github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/4681).

Comment: We have repro for the enlarge image issue and raised a bug for that. We are checking about the embedded hyperlink issue and will update you

Comment: We have repro for the embedded hyperlink issue as well and raised a bug. We will inform you once we get any update. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding Image enlarge issue: We tried it again in Teams desktop version 1.4.00.32167 and it worked fine, however issue persists in Web client (Chrome browser)

Comment: The embedded hyperlink issue seems to be fixed. Please verify once

Comment: Yes, we are verifying and let you know the further updates.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT we got a confirmation from our internal team and it's working fine now.